# Multiple word search in Subversion

Tags: svn, search, version-control, full-text-search

Say I have the url for subversion directory. I mainly browse through it using tortoiseSVN on windows.

How can search the contents of files in that directory (and its subfolders) for 3 separate words (each being a different search):

ie

```
foo
bar
blah
```

And then get results for which files contain that word.
ie

```
foo (23 hits)
my.xml
the.txt

bar (9 hits)
other.txt

blah (178 hits)
new.xml
fake.txt
old.xml
other.xml
```

Comment: what svn client and OS are you using?

Comment: @ChrisDrappier - svn client is TortoiseSVN 1.6.11.20210. OS is WinXP SP2.

Comment: BTW, question unrelated to svn and version-control tags, isn't it? You **even don't request** "historical" aspect of search

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a native solution to what you want.

I'd make a simple batch file myself.  It won't give you EXACTLY what you asked for, but pretty close.

Alternatively have a search for 'baregrep' and see if that does it for you (I haven't used it).

This is what I'd do:

**1) Install cygwin**

This gives you a decent grep (amongst a bunch of other things that you can ignore if you like). grep is a really good tool for finding stuff in text files (like code). Windows XP find is just not up to it.
http://cygwin.com/index.html

**2) figure out the grep command you'll need**

Which is this:

```
grep -r -i --include "*" --exclude-dir ".svn" "foo" .
```

Broken down:

```
-r  == recursive
-i  == ignore case (remove this if you want case sensitive)
--include "*"     == include all files
--exclude-dir ".svn" == tells grep to ignore everything in the hidden subversion folders
"foo"    == what we're looking for
.        == start from the current directory
```

So this command says 'look in all the files beneath this folder, but not in the .svn folders for "foo" '

Stick that in a batch file (e.g. called `findsource.bat`) , somewhere on the path.
To do this, you'll want to replace "foo" with "%1"

```
grep -r -i --include "*" --exclude-dir ".svn" "%1" .
```

Personally, I'd leave it there.

You can then use your batch file from the command line.
CD to the root of your source tree.

```
findsource foo
```

If you want the count of hits you could pipe it to another tool that comes with cygwin - `wc`

```
findsource foo | wc -l
```